# make tap event smooth on ipad

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, events

I have made Divslider application. when I try DivSlider on ipad it works fine just problem is tapping is not smooth , if I tap smoothly then image is not sliding in center  and if I tap harder then it works ? how can I smooth tap ?

```
  $('#myImageFlow').append('<div id='+id+' class="sliderImage"  height="'+height+'"  width="'+ width +'" onclick="">
```

this is the line where `onclick =""`. I have applied because it was before it tap was not working in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tap event, http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

```
$(function() {
    // Bind the tapHandler callback function to the tap event on div.box
    $( "#yourDivID" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );

    // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'tap' class to it
    function tapHandler( event ) {
        // your event
    }
});
```

Or, use vclick instead of onclick..

```
$( document ).on( "vclick", "#yourDivID", function() {
  // 
});
```

Comment: i am using touch, touchStart event

Comment: In native UIKit you use TouchUp event.